# Deleted all item when click on delete button and how to implement the edit/update functionality using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `React.js` and I need to implement the delete and update functionality. Here I have done some coding but in case of delete one element, its deleting all from the array list.

Here is my code:

TodoList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems";
import "./TodoList.css";
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state={
      items:[]
    }
    this.addItem=this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.editItem = this.editItem.bind(this);
  }
  addItem(e){
    var itemArray = this.state.items;
    if (this.inputElement.value !== '') {
      itemArray.unshift({
        text:this.inputElement.value,
        key:Date.now()
      })
      this.setState({
        items:itemArray
      })
      this.inputElement.value='';
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  deleteItem(key) {
    var filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(function (item) {
      return (item.key !== key);
    });

    this.setState({
      items: filteredItems
    });
  }
  editItem(key){

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="header">
          <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
            <input ref={(a)=>this.inputElement=a} placeholder="enter task">
            </input>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <TodoItems entries={this.state.items} delete={this.deleteItem} edit={this.editItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

TodoItems.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class TodoItems extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);

  }
  edit(key){
    this.props.edit(key);
  }
  delete(key){
    this.props.delete(key);
  }
  createTasks(item) {
    return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}<a href="" className="button bg_green" onClick={()=>this.edit(item.key)}>Edit</a><a href=""className="button bg_red" onClick={()=>this.delete(item.key)}>Delete</a></li>
  }

  render() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

    return (
      <ul className="theList">
          {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};


export default TodoItems;
```

My problem is when I am trying to delete any item from the list, All items are removing. Here Also I need to implement the `edit and update` functionality means once user will click on edit button the respective value will display on the text box and user will change it and save after click on Add button.

Comment: first check what filter return to you, think it return empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is this:

```
href=""
```

Either use `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`, or remove the `href` from `a` tag. It will work properly.

**[Working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/ewj1ur3u/)** (changed only `href=""` to `href="#"`)

Comment: Yes right but I need to implement the edit update functionality.  Can I get any help from you ?

Comment: sure, try to implement let me know if you face any issue :)

Comment: Ok, Let me to try and let you know ?

Comment: I did like this `editItem(key){
    this.state.items.map(function(item){
      if (item.key==key) {
        this.inputElement.value=item.text;
      }
    })
  }` to click on edit button but getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputElement' of undefined` error.

Comment: forgot to bind the map callback method, use this: `editItem(key){ 
 this.state.items.map(item => { 
  if (item.key==key) { this.inputElement.value=item.text; } 
 }) 
}` also map is not required here use `forEach` (just replace map by forEach)

Comment: Ok, thanks let me to try update and let you know it any issue faced.

Comment: Can you just help me regarding the update means not inside the text box I am displaying the edited value but I need to change that value and replace with `this.state's value` by matching the key means here how can I pass the edited key to `addItem` function.

Comment: check this [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/gqu427eq/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your delete button is inside a anchor tag which has a href, so it is causing your page to navigate and hence reloading the page making you believe everything is getting deleted but in reality the page is reloading.
Simply removing the href tag will solve your issue you need to however apply some css to give it a link feel.

Replace your createTasks function with the one below to solve your delete problem.

```
  createTasks(item) {
return (
  <li key={item.key}>
    {item.text}
    <a
      className="button bg_green"
      onClick={() => this.edit(item.key)}
    >
      Edit
    </a>
    <a
      className="button bg_red"
      onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)}
    >
      Delete
    </a>
  </li>
);}
```